# Problem when trying to access some vue routes with Laravel router

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

This is the problem : some vue routes don't work with Laravel router whereas others are working.

This one works :

```
Route::get('/dishesV2/edit/{id}', function () {
    return view('back.nutritionV2.index');
});
```

Whereas this one does not :

```
Route::get('/mealPlansV2/edit/{id}', function () {
    return view('back.nutritionV2.index');
});
```

The error thrown when I try to access to the second route is thrown by a route called after the creation of the vue component.. After the component is created, it's calling for the following route :

```
Route::get('/mealPlansV2/{id}/{day}','MealPlansV2Controller@fetchMealPlanDay');
```

[image]

And when I dd the parameters called by this route, I have the parameters of the route '/mealPlansV2/edit/{id}'...

Second problem is when I call the route columns in Laravel :

```
Route::get('/mealPlansV2/columns',function () {
    return view('back.nutritionV2.index');
});
```

What's returned is the axios request "fetchMealPlans" that is called inside the components "columns" instead of the vue route columns...

[image]

This is how my vue routes look like :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/mealPlansV2/columns',
            name: 'MealPlansColumns',
            component: MealPlansColumns,
        },
        {
            path: '/mealPlansV2/edit/:id',
            name: 'MealPlansEdit',
            component: MealPlansEdit,
        },
        {
            path: '/dishesV2/columns',
            name: 'DishesColumns',
            component: DishesColumns,
        },
        {
            path: '/dishesV2/edit/:id',
            name: 'DishesEdit',
            component: DishesEdit,
        },
    ],
});
```

Only the route DishesEdit works in my app.

Thanks for the help and do not hesitate if I haven't been clear on some points.

Comment: please make your question more clear and detailed.

Comment: I've added screenshots to let you see what is displayed if I chose to open a link rendered by vuejs in a new tab. If I simply click on the link, the vuejs route works fine